# Returning interfaces in Golang

Tags: struct, interface, go

I am trying to write a method on a struct that takes in a interface type and returns that interface type but converted to the appropriate type.

```
type Model interface {
    GetEntity()
}

type TrueFalseQuestions struct {
   //some stuff
}

func (q *TrueFalseQuestions) GetEntity() {
   //some stuff
}

type MultiQuestions struct {
    //some stuff
}

func (q *MultiQuestions) GetEntity() {
    //some stuff
}


type Manager struct {
}


func (man *Manager) GetModel(mod Model) Model {
    mod.GetEntity()
    return mod
}

func main() {
    var man Manager

    q := TrueFalseQuestions {}
    q = man.GetModel(&TrueFalseQuestions {})
}
```

So when I call `GetModel()` with type `TrueFalseQuestions` I want to automatically return a `TrueFalseQuestions` type. I figured that would mean that my `GetModel()` method should return a `Model` type. That way if I pass a `MultiQuestion` type a `MultiQuestion` struct is returned.

Comment: Please state what your actual question is. Ideally, your post contains a sentence that ends with a question mark and asks a concrete question. I'm not quite sure what your actual question is.

Comment: @FUZxxl He wants to return the actual "struct" from his `GetModel` func, but it doesn't work that way, he has to use type assertion, check both answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly return a `TrueFalseQuestions` when the return type is `Model`. It will always be implicitly wrapped in a `Model` interface.

To get the `TrueFalseQuestions` back, you need to use a type-assertion. (you also need watch out for pointers vs values)

```
// this should be a pointer, because the interface methods all have pointer receivers
q := &TrueFalseQuestions{}
q = man.GetModel(&TrueFalseQuestions{}).(*TrueFalseQuestions)
```

That of course can panic if you got a `MultiQuestions`, so you should check the `ok` value, or use a type switch

```
switch q := man.GetModel(&TrueFalseQuestions{}).(type) {
case *TrueFalseQuestions:
    // q isTrueFalseQuestions
case *MultiQuestions:
    // q is MultiQuestions
default:
    // unexpected type
}
```

Comment: +1 I like to use the switch more than the if else, looks simpler and in line with the go style

Answer (score 1):

You can't, however you can use type assertion on the returned value.

```
func main() {
    var man Manager

    tfq := &TrueFalseQuestions{}
    q := man.GetModel(tfq)
    if v, ok := q.(*TrueFalseQuestions); ok {
        fmt.Println("v is true/false", v)
    } else if v, ok := q.(*MultiQuestions); ok {
        fmt.Println("v is mq", v)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("unknown", q)
    }

}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/1fLGqzPbmm)